# Magento configurable product dependent attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, dependencies, content-management-system

i'm working these days on a magento online shop for tools (screws, anchors etc) and i need some help for making depending dropdown attributes.

Every product have Size and Package and the product looks like:

Name: Metal anchor with anti-spin

first dropdown - Size: A and B (let's cosinder just two sizes to be easier)

second dropdown - Package: 100 or 200 (for A), 500 or 1000 (for B)

*Creating combination in the associated products tab is currently allowing the customer to freely select whatever combination which is not desired. (example: A with 500 or B with 200)

*I need when the customer select size A, the second dropdown should  display just 2 packages: 100/200 ... and when the customer select size B, the second dropdown should display just 500/1000

How should i create the products for a dependent dropdown? thank you very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create each configuration as an associated simple product and associate it to a configurable product. For ex,

1. Metal anchor with anti-spin (size A, package 100)
2. Metal anchor with anti-spin (size A, package 200)
3. Metal anchor with anti-spin (size B, package 500)
4. Metal anchor with anti-spin (size B, package 1000)

Then associate those products to the configurable product. Then you can see package 100, 200 with size A and package 500, 1000 with package B

Comment: i did this already .... but when i'm going in front end and select Size A, in the second dropdown i have all 4 packages instead of just 2 specific packages for that size...what am i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the configurable product first and then there is a quick create option in "Associated products" tab of the configurable product. There you should create each combination of your simple associated products as below:

1. size A, package 100
2. size A, package 200
3. size B, package 500
4. size B,package 1000

Save the product and then reindex if not set to on save.

The above will work fine if you haven't made much customizations to your magento and also depends on any another 3rd party modules like "Simple Configurable Products"

Comment: What do you mean with much customization? Anyway as i said, i did that already, exactly as you said, and my drop downs still intersect all sizes and packages, and i don't know why. It may cause that something from the theme i already installed on my magento shop? thank you

Comment: By customization, I meant the theme level / functionality level changes by overriding magento's default. This can be a module or a change in the template (phtml) file.You can compare the phtml files first:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml against the same the file in your custom theme (app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml)

Comment: i installed a clean magento shop, to check if the theme is my problem and the answer is "yes and no" .. On the clean magento, when select Size A .. in the 2nd dropdown appears all 4 packages, but they are grey, and ca't be selected ... but are still there and they should be hiden ... i really don't know what to do :(

Comment: Which theme you set? rwd?